# PHP with MYSQL search

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to show the 5 first users with more wins in my webpage and im using this code:

```
<?php
     $rs1 = mysql_query("SELECT won,id,name,avatar,games FROM `users` GROUP BY won DESC LIMIT 5");  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs1))
    $won = round($row[0],2);
    $id = $row[1];
    $name = $row[2];
    $name=secureoutput($name);
    $avatar = $row[3];  
    $games = $row[4];   
        echo'<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
             <div class="widget-bg-color-icon card-box fadeInDown animated" style="height: 170px;">
            <div class="datas">
            <br>
            <a href="profile.php?action=view&id='.$steamid.'" target="_BLANK"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/e3/'.$avatar.'" width="100px" alt="user-img" class="img-circle hoverZoomLink">
                        <h2 style="margin-top: 30px;"> ' .$name.'</h2></a>
                        <div class="">
                        <p><font color="green">TOTAL WON: $'.$won.'</font></p>
                        <p><font color="green">TOTAL GAMES: '.$games.'</font></p>
                        </div> 
            </div> 
            </div> 
            </div>
        ';
}

                        ?>
```

And im getting the the correct ones but now i want to show one difrent image for each place. 
Example the guy in 1st will appear with one image located at "images/ranks/1.png" and the 2nd will have the "images/ranks/2.png" etc..
How can i do that? how can i tell that the guy with more wins will get one images and the guy above will get the other image etc?

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Saw `mysql_` function, immediately stopped reading. http://php.net/mysql-query

Comment: What @NiettheDarkAbsol is trying to say is that you should always the PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and should never use the mysql_ functions oh and while you're at it read up on XSS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have ordered the resultset using SQL, just create a new variable e.g. `$rank` that increments as you loop over the resultset.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT won, id, name, avatar, games FROM `users` GROUP BY won DESC LIMIT 5");  

$rank = 1;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // missing bracket!!!
    $row['won'] = round($row['won'], 2);
    $row['name'] = secureoutput($row['name']); // simplified
    $image = "images/ranks/$rank.png"; // images/ranks/1.png, images/ranks/2.png, etc...

    echo '
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
        <div class="widget-bg-color-icon card-box fadeInDown animated" style="height: 170px;">
            <div class="datas">
                <br>
                <a href="profile.php?action=view&id=' . $steamid . '" target="_blank"><img src="https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/e3/' . $row['avatar'] .'" width="100px" alt="user-img" class="img-circle hoverZoomLink">
                <h2 style="margin-top: 30px;">' . $row['name'] .'</h2></a>
                <div>
                    <p><font color="green">TOTAL WON: $' . $row['won'] . '</font></p>
                    <p><font color="green">TOTAL GAMES: ' . $row['games'] . '</font></p>
                </div> 
            </div> 
        </div> 
        </div>
    ';

    $rank++;
}
?>
```

Few other things:

- I decided to use mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array as it is more readable;
- Don't waste variables if you don't need them;
- And most important of all things, STOP USING MYSQL_* functions!

Comment: what should i use instead of mysql_ funcions? @Mikey i should use msqli?

Comment: Personally, I have never used mysqli and have always use PDO. According to the answers on this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons), there are more features in PDO than mysqli.